# Nested pattern matching in Lean for destructing hypothesis

Tags: lean

Let us look at the example of some lemma (whose statement and whether it is true or not is irrelevant for this discussion):

```
lemma L1 : forall (n m: ℕ) (p : ℕ → Prop), (p n ∧ ∃ (u:ℕ), p u ∧ p m) ∨ (¬p n ∧ p m) → n = m :=
begin
  intros n m p H, cases H with H H,
    {cases H with H1 H2, cases H2 with u H2, cases H2 with H2 H3, sorry},
    {cases H with H1 H2, sorry}
end
```

The point I wish to highlight here is when destructing my hypothesis with the `cases` tactic,
I did not know any other way but to use the tactic several times (once for each 'layer' so to speak).

If I look at the same lemma in Coq:

```
Lemma L1 : forall (n m:nat) (p:nat -> Prop), 
    (p n /\ exists (u:nat), p u /\ p m) \/ (~p n /\ p m) -> n = m.
Proof.
    intros n m p [[H1 [u [H2 H3]]]|[H1 H2]].
    - admit.
    -
Show.
```

I am able to destruct my assumption with a single nested pattern match.

I am guessing I can do the same sort of thing in Lean but I do not know how. I would be grateful to be told as I find the nested pattern match very convenient in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need [mathlib](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib) for this, and `import tactic.rcases`. You can use the `rcases` tactic.

```
import tactic.rcases

lemma L1 : forall (n m: ℕ) (p : ℕ → Prop), (p n ∧ ∃ (u:ℕ), p u ∧ p m) ∨ (¬p n ∧ p m) → n = m :=
begin
  intros n m p H, 
  rcases H with ⟨H1, u, H2, H3⟩ | ⟨H1, H2⟩,
  
end
```